# keyframe loading animation when loading page

Tags: html, css, keyframe

I am trying to load an unordered list with animation using CSS3 keyframe.
My problem is the list get loaded before the animation begun. 
And I want it to load only after the animation.

here is a result of what I achieved so far http://jsbin.com/agelix/1/edit

HTML

```
       <ul  
          class="loadingdiv" >          
          <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">4</a></li> 
       </ul>
```

CSS

```
 .loadingdiv li{  
    -moz-animation: loading 1s  alternate;  
}


.loadingdiv li:nth-of-type(2) {    
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.4s;
}
.loadingdiv li:nth-of-type(3) {     
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.6s;
}
.loadingdiv li:nth-of-type(4) {    
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.8s;
}
.loadingdiv li:nth-of-type(5) {    
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.9s; 
}


@-moz-keyframes loading {
  0% {-moz-transform: translateZ(0); opacity:0} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, after lot click click click... and some info from [css3files.com](http://www.css3files.com), It worked.

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/ehujis/1/edit

her is what I did.
HTML:

```
  <ul>  
     <li class="box fade-in">1</li>
     <li class="box fade-in">2</li>
     <li class="box fade-in">3</li>
     <li class="box fade-in">4</li>    
  </ul>
```

CSS:

```
 /* make keyframes that tell the start state and the end state of our object */
@keyframes fadeIn { 
  from { opacity:0;   } 
  to { opacity:1;  } }     

.fade-in {
    opacity:0;  /* make things invisible upon start */ 
    animation:fadeIn ease-out 3s;  
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;  
    animation-duration:.8s;  
}              

li:nth-of-type(1)  { 
animation-delay: 0.6s;             
}                

 li:nth-of-type(2)  { 
animation-delay: 1.3s;
}

  li:nth-of-type(3) { 
animation-delay: 2s;
}
   li:nth-of-type(4) { 
animation-delay: 2.7s;
}
```

Note: this code is based from the graphicfusiondesign.com article: [Creating fancy CSS3 fade in animations on page load](http://graphicfusiondesign.com/blog/design/creating-fancy-css3-fade-in-animations-on-page-load/)

here is a demo